# Can't login into sftp

Tags: freebsd

I'm get this error when trying to connect through filezilla with sftp:

on server:

```
fatal: Write failed: Broken pipe [preauth]
```

on filezilla:

```
Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
```

I previously could connect to it, now I can't and I've no idea why.

Comment: have a look on the server into logs. There should be reason for the disconnecting. Also verbose client log may help you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have you free space in /var/log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SSHing to the box with the same account and double check if .profile or .bash_profile or any other file doesn't write any output on the screen. Once I had this weird problem that because a script wrote output to the screen, I couldn't sftp to the box.